# How to notify all People in a regular message (not Announcement) in a specific group (not All Company) in Yammer?

Tags: yammer

From what I understand, to notify everyone in Yammer there are several possibilities:

- post in the All Company group;
- post an Announcement in a group, all the people from this group will
  be notified;
- post a regular post (Update) anywhere and ***manually*** add all the
  people to notify in the field (or add the @ in the text for everyone).

Is there any less tedious way to achieve the behaviour from the last option above (not realistic with a high number of People)? I.e., without having to post in All Company or to make an Announcement or to manually tag all the people? (Is there a possibility to create a "All" alias that could be use like @All to notify everyone? Or to create groups of People and notify these groups, e.g. @group1?)

So: **is there a simple and efficient way to notify everyone (all the People of the company) in a regular message (Update) done in a specific group within a Yammer network?**

Comment: Can you just mention @AllCompany from that other group?

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDoroshenko but it doesn't seem so. Is it supposed to work automatically, do you use this? This doesn't notify anyone, and "AllCompany" is not an option in the 'Add people to notify' area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't support for this in the product. If you need to notify everyone you should use an announcement because that's what it's designed to do.

Notifying everyone in a similar way to sending an email to everyone is not considered to be a best practice within a social tool like Yammer. The message will be surfaced in Yammer for users, and they'll see other people replying or liking it.

You missed out on how to @mention users from code. To @mention a small number of users (best practive) you can take the name (user permalink) element from the users.json (or other user endpoint). Then post it in the body of a message as @name replacing "name" with the permalink value.

Comment: Regarding the possibility I missed, unless I didn't get what you say, this is what I was mentioning with "or add the @ in the text" (last point). But this still is tedious once we need to notify more than a few people. So I understand that there is no solution for this in Yammer, and that announcements is the closest we can get. A bit a shame in our small (and disciplined) case - technically, if we are afraid of abuses, one could imagine a possibility to create aliases for some groups of people (possibly all) by admin and then allowing the @suchgroup to be used for efficient notifications...

Comment: It's not necessarily explicit abuses it's the tension between what other people think you are interested in, and what you can tolerate. Many tools fail because posting to everyone via that tool becomes the norm in an organisation and then individuals give up on it because it's too spammy for them to keep up. It might be best to post an item on https://yammer.uservoice.com/ for product team review.